# How can I make IntelliJ fold variable types?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Being used to languages that provide type inference (C++, Scala) I find code like this difficult to read:

```
ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(0);
```

as the type is repeated. Is there a way to make IntelliJ fold the type of the variable so that I can read and write it like this:

```
var classWriter = new ClassWriter(0);
```

but it actually stores it on disk as `ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(0);`?

Comment: displaying something different than the file contains seems very error-prone to me.

Answer (score 9):

The **Advanced Java Folding** plugin (by JetBrains) adds folding for *variable declarations*, among other things.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/9320-advanced-java-folding

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, and it's probably not a good idea for the following reason.

With java it is common to instantiate a concrete implementation type and refer to it via the abstract type.

For example:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In this circumstance, if you could just write `var myList = new ArrayList<String>();` - what type is `myList` actually? Is it `List<String>` or `ArrayList<String>`?

Strong typing is central to java and the example above illustrates why.

Java 7 improves upon this somewhat, where the readability for parameterized types can use a diamond:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

In any case, I would suggest to simply try and get used to the "java way" of doing this.